# Ubuntu 17.04 Greeting Display LightDM Resolution

Tags: display, lightdm, 17.04, display-resolution, unity-greeter

Many people seem to encounter the problem, that the greeting screen is displayed in the wrong (a lower) resolution. After logging in, the resolution is fine. This behaviour was "introduced" two years ago, AFAIR; before everything used to be fine.

I tried setting up [LightDM resolution](http://www.sudo-juice.com/lightdm-resolution), I tried xrandr as startup application, but none of the approaches helped, the resolution is always low, no matter

Is there a fix that will work? And as "bonus question": Does anybody know, what changed some versions agao, that broke the correct screen resolution?

Comment: Am I really the only person, who has this problem? :'(

Comment: I have the same problem too

Comment: I feel less alone now, thank you. It might be, that the resolution is not the problem, but that the login screen is automatically set to zoom factor 200 %. But I also did not find a way to fix that. I do not dare to open another thread with that question though.

Comment: For safety purposes I'm doing tests in the VM Ware just in case my dual boot one backstabs me. Still haven't found the solution yet

Comment: That is a wise choice - I also do not dare to fiddle around with boot settings a lot - that's why I still have not managed to have a nice picture as background in GRUB, but that is another story. :)